# <a> or <button> only can be effect when clicking on the top half part

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have encountered a very strange problem when doing when React project. I have to render a list of items that include a button. But the button can only be triggered when clicking on the top half part. When I move my mouse to the downside of the button, nothing happens, and it would not even cursor. I changed it to  tag a and it behaves the same, only top part works.The function works fine when clicking on the top part so I do not think it is a problem. But where is the problem then? Please help me, thanks so much.  The code is as follows:

content:

```
    const Array = [{
      title: XXX,
      content: (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Click me
        </button>
      ),
}, ... (there are other elements which I do not write here)]
```

render parts:

```
        {Array
          .map((row, idx) => (
            <div key={idx} className={classes.row}>
              <Typography >{row.title}</Typography>
              <Typography >{row.content}</Typography>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like another element is overlapping it...

Comment: The issue could be within css, would be better to see css codes as well

Comment: Try to remove ```Typography ``` and test it or add a style to the button and give it a ```zIndex: 1```, maybe something is overlapping it

Comment: Look for that kind of thing in your rendered HTML: [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oNLmdQN)